# Page setup input for printer in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to provide a way to enter processes ids for my script [ezkill](https://github.com/Kraymer/ezkill) that would have the same properties than printer page setup inputs we're used to :

- range expansion: `a-e` => `abcde`
- enumeration: 'a,d,e' => `ade`
- mix of the two: 'a-e,g,h' => `abcdegh`

As it's a common pattern I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel on that one. 
Have you knowledge of some existing bash function/program that I could reuse ?

Comment: Where is the need for code here? I don't see a question. If we misunderstood it, do state the exact input needed and the output needed out of it, with what research efforts you made of your own

Answer (score 0):

Simple regular expression matching would do it if you *transform* your patterns.

```
declare -A exps
exps=([range]='a-e', [enum]='a,d,e', [mix]='a-e,g,h')

for c in {a..h}
do
        for k in "${!exps[@]}"
        do
                e="${exps[$k]}"
                printf $'is \'%s\' a match for \'%s\'?: ' "$c" "$e"
                # transform the pattern expression
                [[ "$c" =~ [${e//,}] ]] && printf 'yes' || printf 'no'
                printf '\n'
        done
done
```